# setTimeout no hace nada

Tags: javascript

Soy nuevo programando con JavaScript y tengo el siguiente problema, he hecho un carrusel que funciona correctamente, pero quiero mostrar las imágenes con un fade, es decir, con opacity desde 0 hasta 1. Lo hago con una función que contiene un setTimeout(función(), 2000), pero no hace la pausa. Pongo el código del HTML y del js.

El carrusel funciona bien, pero no hace el fade de la imagen al mostrarla.

Lo he tenido que hacer así porque las imágenes son de distintas alturas y con el carrusel de Bootstrap no se veía bien. Las imágenes de menor altura se muestran en la ajustadas a la parte superior y después se centran verticalmente en la pantalla.

Si utilizo setinterval se va haciendo el fade, pero después de cada vuelta de imágenes, es decir, que cada vez que se termina de recorrer las imágenes se ejecuta una la función FadeImagen una vez.

Como pueden ver en el setTimeout he puesto un intervalo exagerado y ni así se detiene, la imagen se muestra sin hacer pausas.

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Este es el código JavaScript que he escrito.

```js
"use strict";

var actual = 0.1;
var nFoto = 1;
var nFotos = 4;
var foto = document.createElement("img");

function CargaFoto() {
    var contenedorFoto = document.getElementById("contenedorFoto");
    var nomFoto = "imgs/" + nFoto.toString() + ".jpg"

    foto.src = nomFoto;
    foto.className = "mx-auto my-auto";
    foto.style.opacity = 0.0;

    contenedorFoto.innerHTML="";
    contenedorFoto.appendChild(foto);

    FadeImagen();
}

function FadeImagen() {
    foto.style.opacity = actual;

    if (foto.style.opacity == 1.0) {
        return;
    }

    actual += 0.1;

    setTimeout(FadeImagen(), 50000);
}
```

Comment: Set timeout va a ejecutar la funcion FadeImagen dentro de 50 segundos, y luego va a ejecutar la funcion FadeImagen dentro de 50 segundos.. y asi eternamente.. creo que no era lo que queres hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias por responder, lo de los 50 segundos era por probar algo porque ya no sabía que hacer; la función original va con 50 ms.

Ya está solucionado, simplemente el problema eran los paréntesis en la función que se llama desde setTimeout setTimeout(FadeImagen(), 50);.

Lo correcto es setTimeout(FadeImagen, 50);

Gracias nuevamente.